# How to hide certain tabs from displaying in TabNavigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation and I need to hide some tabs while use tab navigation in my app. I want navigation to any screen any screen in tabs navigation but only want to display certain tabs. How should I write Tab navigation ?

```js
const TabNav = TabNavigator ({
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
      }
    },
    Post: {
      screen: Post,
    },
    Browse: {
      screen: Browse,
    },
    Inbox: {
      screen: Inbox,
    },
    More: {
      screen: More,
    },
  })
```

I added my tab navigation now. Suppose I do not want to show Inbox screen but want to use its navigator to navigate to Inbox from any screen and from any screen to Inbox using navigator.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any examples of the things you've tried?

Comment: I added my tab navigation now. Suppose I do not want to show Inbox screen but want to use its navigator to navigate to Inbox from any screen and from any screen to Inbox using navigator.